# fill ListBox according to input control value in onKeyUp function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've a ListBox control

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="XYZ" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="XYZD" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="D" />
 </asp:ListBox>
```

a input :

```
<input id="listBoxFilterTextBox" type="text" onkeyup="FilterListBox()"
```

js functions :

```
 function FilterListBox() {
        var listBox = Get('ListBox1');
        var textBox = Get('listBoxFilterTextBox');

        for (i = 0; i < listBox.options.length; i++) {
            if (listBox.options[i].text.toLowerCase().indexOf(textBox.value.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                listBox.options[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                listBox.options[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }

         function Get(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
         }
```

When I enter 'X' to input control, it brings 'XYZ', 'XYZD'.. It works correctly Firefox and Chrome. But in IE, It doesn't work correctly. How to solve this IE problem?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide OPTION in SELECT in IE with CSS. Instead add second ListBoxSource with all needed options and copy from ListBoxSource to ListBoxSource only those options which satisfy your criteria.